# Aurelia event aggregator sample code to subscribe() is invalid Typescript?

Tags: typescript, aurelia

The contact-manager tutorial on Aurelia's main site shows that for an instance of EventAggregator named ea, the following code can be used in TypeScript to subscribe to a publication:

```
ea.subscribe(ContactViewed, msg => this.select(msg.contact));
```

However, although the required ContactViewed class is properly defined, this syntax will not "compile" within VS 2017 (configured with warnings as errors).

```
Error TS2346 (TS) Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Fortunately, the following "equivalent" syntax does compile and work:

```
ea.subscribe(ContactViewed, function(msg: ContactViewed) {
        this.select(msg.contact);
    });
```

So my question is, why is this syntax documented as valid TypeScript by Aurelia, and/or why won't it work for me?

Thanks

Comment: Does the transpiler give you an error?

Comment: @thebluefox: DOH! Yes, I've updated the content.

Comment: I may have stumbled upon the solution - while implementing another "arrow function" (lambda), I found that putting parens around the argument named msg resolved the TS error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the issue with some parentheses along with type directive:

```
ea.subscribe(ContactViewed, (msg: ContactViewed) => this.select(msg.contact));
```

I'm admittedly a newbie to Aurelia and Typescript, but it makes it so much tougher when the "vendor" docs present tutorial information that doesn't work out-of-the-box. Lesson learned.